# Arcgis rest api service - query to check for numeric in a string field

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api, arcgis-server

I am using Arcgis rest api service query to return only records that have a numeric value in a string field. (actionid is the string field which can be null also)  This is what I am trying so far for the WHERE clause in the ArcGIS REST Services for the feature class:

**TEST 1**

I tried the following for first test using DECIMAL:

```
CAST( (COALESCE(actionid , '0')) AS DECIMAL) > -10000000
```

This is the error I am receiving.

Error:

```
'where' parameter is invalid
```

**TEST 2**

I tried the following for second test using INTEGER:

```
CAST( (COALESCE(actionid , '0')) AS INTEGER) > -10000000
```

This is the error I am receiving.

Error:

```
Unable to perform query. Please check your parameters.
```

So far from my research, it looks like it should support all the above keywords since it uses SQL-92.  What am I missing?  Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue!

The problem is that the **CAST** function will error out if it tries to cast a string to an integer:

```
CAST( (COALESCE(actionid , '0')) AS INTEGER) > -10000000
```

I was able to confirm this was the issue by running the same query but on a different field such as objectid that has no strings.  This works fine:

```
CAST( (COALESCE(objectid , '0')) AS INTEGER) > -10000000
```

I also found out that **ISNUMERIC** does not work in ArcGIS rest api service:

ISNUMERIC(actionid ) = 1

As mentioned by **cabesuon** in the comments, even the following example does not work since it can include values such as **a0**:

```
actionid like '%[0-9]%'
```

So instead of using **CAST** or **ISNUMERIC** use the **NOT LIKE** statement.  The following query is the solution and will return numeric values only as desired:

```
actionid NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

Comment: This solution only checks that a digit is in the value, accepts things like `000`, `a0`, `hello1`, etc

Comment: Thank you cabesuon.  Answer has been updated per your recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try another solution like `ISNUMERIC` function, wich evaluates the parameter and returns `1` if "is" a number, `0` in other case.

With the propose function the solution should be something like,

```
ISNUMERIC(actionid)=1
```